# SQL output date format for all dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to enforce a date format for all output date fields when doing a "Select *" ?
I want all dates to be 'CCYY-MM-DD' on output but I don't want to individually name the columns.

Specifically for MSSQL Server

Comment: What your RDBMS version?

Comment: In what type u did insert ur data at first ?

Comment: Specifically for MS SQL Server

Comment: You can create a function and then use it on all columns

Comment: The date display format will be set in whatever tool you are using to query the SQL Server DB

Comment: @NickW that is a great insight. I'm actually using PERL DBI which is why I'm a bit lost. I don't see any options within PERL DBI for setting date format with MSSQL Server.

Comment: If there is no setting in your query tool then it is probably getting its settings from your OS

Comment: Well, technically it is likely using the account preferences for the current logged-in user. For OP - wouldn't YOU want to see dates using the preferences YOU specify in your account settings? Why do YOU as developer want to force a particular format?